# SFMC account linked to Service Cloud org

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, servicecloud

I just inherited a marketing cloud account and saw that it is connected to a service cloud org.

Please how could I know what it is connected to?

Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a programming question.

Comment: Gio, could you please state clearly and in some detail what you want to know and what you've already investigated and found out?! From my point of view it doesn't need to be a programming question, but I have difficulties to understand what you already know and what you need to know.

Answer (score 1):

Inside Marketing Cloud, go to **Setup**. In Setup’s Quick find box, type **Salesforce Integration**.

There, you will find information about the **Salesforce Org ID** which your Business Unit is connected to and the username of the Salesforce user which is used for the integration:

[image]

Note, that if you have multi-org enabled in Marketing Cloud, you could be connected to multiple Salesforce orgs (maximum one per BU).

If you need more information on Marketing Cloud Connect setup, follow this Trailhead: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/marketing-cloud-connect